# Why are there different נוסחאות when making a bracha over a mitzvah?

Tags: tefilla, blessing

How come some of the berachos we say over mitzvah have the נוסח of :
אשר קדשנו במצוותיו וציוונו **על** אכילת מצה,**על** נתילת ידים, etc.
While over other mitzvahs we say
אשר קדשנו במצוותיו וציוונו **ל**קבוע מזוזה, **ל**הניח תפילין?